# source == button in Java

Tags: java, actionlistener, equals

I was wondering why do we use the sign == when comparing a button to the source in the actionPerformed method?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();

    if(source == button)


}
```

Usually in Java, we use .equals() to compare two objects but in this case we use == instead.

Why ?

Comment: Perhaps a better way to approach it is to have a distinct `ActionListener` for each button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're checking if it actually came from *that specific instance* of `Button`.

You might be able to use equals (implementations often check `obj == this` first), but `==` is appropriate for the use case, and is faster.